# Conflicting definitions for strict quasiconvexity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I believe to have found a problem with conflicting definitions for strict quasiconvexity. Let me first present the two definitions and then a conflicting example.

According to Definition 1 (which is featured on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function)):

A function $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on a convex subset $S$ of a real vector space is strictly quasiconvex if for all $x, y \in S$ with $x \neq y$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$
$$
f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) < \max \{ f(x), f(y)\}
$$

Definition 2, which I have found in several older papers (e.g. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X67900959) and [here](https://www.esaim-m2an.org/articles/m2an/pdf/1972/01/m2an197206R100151.pdf)):

A function $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on a convex subset $S$ of a real vector space is strictly quasiconvex if for all $x, y \in S$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$
$$
f(x) < f(y) \implies f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) < f(y)
$$

An example of where these definitions collide can be found in the [aforementioned paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X67900959):

For $f: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1    & \quad \text{for} \quad x = 0\\
0    & \quad \text{for} -1 \leq x < 0, 0 < x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

The paper uses this example to state that a strictly quasiconvex function need not be quasiconvex. Indeed, under Definition 2 this function would be strictly quasiconvex (because either $x$ or $y$ will be the $0$ point to satisfy the LHS of the implication, so any combination you make with $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ is equal to $0$). However, if you select Definition 1, this is clearly not strictly quasiconvex. For example, take the points $x=-1$ and $y=1$ with $\lambda = 0.5$, then clearly both $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are equal to $0$ but $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) = 1$.

My question is: am I missing something here?

If the answer to this is no, then I have two follow up questions:

- what is the generally used/accepted definition?
- As noted in my example, under Definition 2 a strictly quasiconvex function is not necessarily quasiconvex. Does this also hold for Definition 1? I have a feeling that Definition 1 does say strict quasiconvexity implies quasiconvexity but I'm getting really confused from all these mixed messages.

Comment: I am not yet familiar with Definition 2. Regarding Definition 1 : if you read carefully the Wikipedia link you had it is trivial that a strictly quasiconvex function is quasiconvex. (What you wrote above was the Definition 1 of *strictly* quasi convex. You should add *strictly*.)

Comment: You are indeed correct. I made a typo when writing down the definitions but now changed them to say _strictly_ quasiconvex. I also thought that it is trivial that a strictly quasiconvex function is quasiconvex. That is why I thought Definition 2, and what it implies, was extremely strange.

Comment: It is not necessarily extremely strange. We are only not familiar enough with a notion that has obviously changed over time.